# Maximum PEP8 length for Sage doc example

Tags: sage

I want to follow the maximum line length (79 characters)
according to pep8. I want to do that in the following code.
Specifically, in the line commented with "here". I tried
to use "" but my test does not pass because `llllll`
returns an entire line and not a "broken" line.

```py
def test():
    """
    EXAMPLES::
    
        sage: from oo.rrr.aaa.fff import XXX
        sage: M = MMMM(XXX)
        sage: _, llllll = M.rrrrr(M.c("y"))
        sage: llllll
        'lore_word(array1d(0, [xor_tttt,xor_xxxxx,xor_xxxxx,xor_xxxxx,xor_x,xor_xxx_tttt,xor_xxxxx,xor_xxxx,xor_xxxxx]))'  # here
    """
    return 0
```

Comment: Idea: modify the method rrrrr so that its output has spaces after commas.

Comment: Ideally, share a minimal complete example.